# Nativescript Playground: Uncaught error message

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

First time using Nativescript, ran a simple script that uses nativescript-contacts for iOS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-contacts) and giving me the following error:

```
2019-05-21 19:20:32.059 nsplaydev[284:10490] PlayLiveSync: Initializing NativeScript runtime at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F19FB79E-A435-49E6-A978-308E1C976F0A/Documents/Playground/LiveSync
CONSOLE WARN file:///app/c210e62cd8f442b19651.worker.js:31673:12: Objective-C class name "UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateImpl" is already in use - using "UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateImpl2" instead.
2019-05-21 19:20:32.108 nsplaydev[284:10454] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception
2019-05-21 19:20:32.109 nsplaydev[284:10454] PlayLiveSync: Sending crash report
2019-05-21 19:20:32.132 nsplaydev[284:10439] PlayLiveSync: Successfully sent uncaught error message onZN396nE
2019-05-21 19:20:32.133 nsplaydev[284:10439] PlayLiveSync: Successfully sent log message onZN396nE
```

How/where do I see the error log? what is that unique identifier (onZN396nE) that it generates?

Thanks!

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding,You can not run the program on Playground that has dependencies on native APIs as playground has some [limitations](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/the-powers-of-nativescript-and-the-nativescript-playground).  However, it contains some of the most useful NativeScript plugins, and as such, covers a wide range of tasks you need to perform while developing apps.

[nativescript-contacts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-contacts#android-caveats) plugin requires permissions and interacting with an part of the platform API is not very straight froward.

Answer (score 0):

What do you know?   I found the problem:

Part (a) code given below.  The templateUrl is wrong below.  It should be "login/login.component.hmtl"

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "gr-login",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry.   Posted on the right page.  First time on stack overflow.